# python resetting of my key/value after few iterations

Tags: python, dictionary

I am not sure if this is a code syntax error I am doing, or some weird-pythonic iteration:
As part of a longer code, I provide an input file "Input.txt". The code is supposed to:

1. Iterate over each line of the input file
2. Use the third column to generate "keys" for an empty dictionary
3. Use the first column as the "value" for the corresponding key in each line
4. If the key (i.e. what's in the third column) exists in the dictionary, then just append the value (1st column).

Problem: For some reason, python resets the values/keys after 5 iterations. to make things clearer and try to trace the error, I printed out the processes resulting from the code running.

Input file:

```
MouseGene   m_gene_FC   MouseLncRNA m_lnc_FC    HumanGene   h_gene_FC   HumanLncRNA h_lnc_FC    #_genes_Tested
Spata1  0.472455825 Gm20645 0.507222015 Spata1  0.472455825 Gm20645 0.507222015 1109
XX  0.472455825 Gm20645 0.507222015 Spata1  0.472455825 Gm11216 0.031375848 1109
YY  0.472455825 Gm20645 0.507222015 Spata1  0.472455825 Gm26964 0.372023062 1109
ZZ  0.472455825 Gm20645 0.507222015 Spata1  0.472455825 1110019D14Rik   0.272607682 1109
JJ  0.472455825 Gm20645 0.507222015 Spata1  0.472455825 C430042M11Rik   0.062670386 1109
Spata1  0.472455825 Gm20645 0.507222015 Spata1  0.472455825 Gm13166 0.210586702 1109
Spata1  0.472455825 Gm20645 0.507222015 Spata1  0.472455825 Gm26825 0.043691414 1109
```

Code:

```
mouse_dict = {}
infile=open("Input.txt", "r")
for line in infile.readlines()[1:]: #skips header
    cols = line.rstrip().split('\t')
    if cols[2] in mouse_dict and cols[0] not in mouse_dict[cols[2]]: #if key is there, but the value is not, then append it
        mouse_dict[cols[2]].append(cols[0])
        print "key:", cols[2], "is there but value", cols[0], "is not"
        print "Values for", cols[2], "are now:", mouse_dict[cols[2]]
    else:
        mouse_dict[cols[2]] = [cols[0]]
        print "key:", cols[2], "is not there and value", cols[0], "is added"

print "My final dictionary items are:", mouse_dict.items()
```

I end up getting the following output on the screen:

```
key: Gm20645 is not there and value Spata1 is added
key: Gm20645 is there but value XX is not
Values for Gm20645 are now: ['Spata1', 'XX']
key: Gm20645 is there but value YY is not
Values for Gm20645 are now: ['Spata1', 'XX', 'YY']
key: Gm20645 is there but value ZZ is not
Values for Gm20645 are now: ['Spata1', 'XX', 'YY', 'ZZ']
key: Gm20645 is there but value JJ is not
Values for Gm20645 are now: ['Spata1', 'XX', 'YY', 'ZZ', 'JJ']
key: Gm20645 is not there and value Spata1 is added
key: Gm20645 is not there and value Spata1 is added
My final dictionary items are: [('Gm20645', ['Spata1'])]
```

I expect that the Gm20645 key to have ['Spata1', 'XX', 'YY', 'ZZ', 'JJ'] as final keys output.

As you can tell, only "Spata1" is left after the iteration, and someone the Gm20645 key is lost as you can see from the line:
key: Gm20645 is not there and value Spata1 is added

My original file consists of >1000 rows, so i initially thought it is memory problem. However, even when i cut it down to the small lines above I am getting this error (as exactly in the above example). I also thought that python allows a maximum number of values per key in a dictionary and then automatically resets, but i did not find any evidence that this is true. I never encountered such an error and I cant figure out a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Think about what you do when `cols[0]` is in `mouse_dict[cols[2]]`. Also, fix your indentation. It really matters.

Comment: ohhhhh!!!! i am resetting it as it is jumping to the else. How dumb of me! Been looking at this for past 4 hours and trying every single method.

Comment: Hey, it happens to everybody. :) For stuff like this I find drawing a flowchart & checking all the paths before I write code can be helpful.

Comment: Once you've figured out the correct logic you should write an answer: it may help future readers with a similar problem.

Comment: Yes, of cours.e I am just fixing the code and will update it with an answer. I want to make sure it works on my large file to avoid such (stupid) mistakes.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the pat on the back  and advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were going wrong in the If condition. For it to insert into the list both the condition must be true. Because it is the `and` operation. So when `not in` for Spata1 fails it goes to else.

Try something like this.

```
if cols[2] in mouse_dict:
    if cols[0] not in mouse_dict[cols[2]]:
        mouse_dict[cols[2]].append(cols[0])
        print "key:", cols[2], "is there but value", cols[0], "is not"
        print "Values for", cols[2], "are now:", mouse_dict[cols[2]]
else:
    mouse_dict[cols[2]] = [cols[0]]
    print "key:", cols[2], "is not there and value", cols[0], "is added"
```

Comment: that works BUT, it then duplicates some values.  No? Thanks-

Comment: No. Because if that value is already in the list It does nothing. There is a if condition inside of that if condition.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it was a code error from my end: When key is in the dictionary and cols[0] is in mouse_dict[cols[2]] (i.e. value is there), it skips the if and goes to the "else" statement which causes my dictionary to reset as a new key and new value, and that continues. To fix this problem, use this code:

```
mouse_dict = {}
infile=open("Input.txt", "r")
for line in infile.readlines()[1:]: #skips header
    cols = line.rstrip().split('\t')
    if cols[2] not in mouse_dict.keys(): #First it checks if key is NOT there. if it is not, it adds it. if the key is in the dictionary it goes to the elif
        mouse_dict[cols[2]] = [cols[0]]
        print "key:", cols[2], "is not there and value", cols[0], "is added"
    elif (cols[2] in mouse_dict.keys()) and (cols[0] not in mouse_dict[cols[2]]): #if key is there, but the value is not, then append it
        mouse_dict[cols[2]].append(cols[0])
        print "key:", cols[2], "is there but value", cols[0], "is not"
        print "Values for", cols[2], "are now:", mouse_dict[cols[2]]
print "My final dictionary items are:", mouse_dict.items()
```

I tested it on my larger file and it worked. if anyone has any other suggestions please let me know. I deserved the thumbs down :D.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to do `if thing not in some_dict.keys()`. You can just do `if thing not in some_dict`, which is much more efficient, especially in Python 2. Doing `some_dict.keys()` has to create a `list` of the keys, and then do a linear search through that list, whereas doing an `in` test on a `dict` (or `set`) is a hash table lookup, which is a very fast operation.